Blender Compositing, no file output
In my scene I've setup up compositing nodes.  At the end, if I connect the glare output to the viewer, I see the composited image.  If I duplicate that link or singly connect it to the file output node, I get no file output.  What mistake did I make?


You have to actually fire off a real render with F12 or the Render menu for any File Output nodes to be triggered. The auto render for the Viewer node won’t do that.

F5 starts a render? I learn every day something new, never tried that...

Interesting.  I can see the compositor working when I disconnect and then connect to the viewer output.  I did as you suggested and performed another render with both outputs connected and I can see the output file.  Thanks.

@GordonBrinkmann oops, I was thinking Python. It’s F12, not F5.

@Robinson The Compositor is working to produce the output for the Viewer node, but the compositing itself does not trigger saving the file. Only initiating a render does.
